# Texture painting individual pixels

Tags: texture-painting

I'm trying to make a Minecraft skin, and I noticed that even when using Constant falloff, the brush size is still too big to paint individual pixels like Photoshop's Pen tool does:
[image: Brush with a radius of 1 px in relation to actual pixels]

(The brush in the image has a radius of 1 pixel)

Is there any setting, brush or tool I might be missing that would allow me to paint in individual pixels?

Answer (score 3):

You can **disable Anti-Aliasing** in the Advanced dropdown menu, then use a **custom falloff** to regulate the radius of the brush.

[image: Activating Anti-Aliasing]

[image: Creating a custom falloff]

The first handle is at `X=0 Y=1`, the second at `X=0.5 Y=1`, and the third at `X=0.501 Y=0`. This will assure you only paint one pixel at a time, you can change it to your liking since it also changes it's responsiveness.